# Bug? Changing order of assertions affects satisfiability

Tags: z3

After changing the order of assertions in unsat query it becomes sat.

The query structure is:

```
definitions1
assertions1
definitions2
bad_assertions
check-sat
```

I sort bad_assertions with Python's sorted function, and this makes Unsat query Sat.

Z3 versions 4.0, 4.1; Ubuntu 12.04

Unfortunately, queries are quite large which makes them difficult to debug,
so I can provide any other additional info if.

Here are originally unsat [query](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/444947/posts/unsat_query.smt2) with marked lines for mixing, and a simple python [script](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/444947/posts/lines_mixer.py) to mix lines in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the problem reported in your question. Both examples are satisfiable. The script that produces `unsat` is exposing a bug in the datatype theory. I fixed the bug, and the fix will be available in Z3 4.2. Since this is a soundness bug, we will release version 4.2 very soon. In the meantime, you can workaround the bug by using the option `RELEVANCY=0` in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like a bug.
sat/unsat should of course not depend on ordering. 
If packaging up a repro is difficult, then one way to help us debug 
the problem, once you have confidence in what triggers the bug, 
is to use "open_log()" to dump a trace of all interactions with Z3. 
You should use "open_log" before other calls to Z3. 
We can then replay the log without your sources.

Comment: updated post and included python script to mix marked lines and a special query.